# Using data in <select> options in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to delete a row from an MySQL database. The row that I'd like to delete is displayed in a  box, with each  being obtained via a loop and SELECT statement.

I've already got the rows in the database being displayed accordingly; however, I'd like a button that once pressed, would delete the selected option from the database.

Here is my current code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>Patient Name:</label>
  <br><br>
  <select name="patient" id="patient">
    <?php 
      $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "as2");
      $result = $conn->query("SELECT patientID, patientName, address FROM patient ORDER BY patientName ASC");
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        $patientName = $row['patientName'];
        $address = $row['address'];

      echo "<option value=\"patient\">" .$patientName. ",  ".$address."</option>";
      }
    ?>
        </select>
  <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Record">
</form>
```

How would I go about making the "Delete Record" button delete the selected option from the database?

Comment: Start with the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: I know the syntax behind deleting a row with MySQL. I just can't get the query to 'interact' with the highlighted select option.

Comment: see the answer below then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first record (patientID) in a string

```
$patientID = $row['patientID'];
```

then Add `$patientID`to (option value) so it become :

```
echo "<option value=".$patientID.">" .$patientName. ",  ".$address."</option>";
```

then add this code After everything (ofc outside the "while" loop) :

```
<?php  

$selected_patient = $_POST['patient'];

 if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' 
     && isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['patient']) ) {

  if( !empty($_POST['patient']) ){
   $patient_ID = mysql_real_escape_string($selected_patient);

 if ( $conn->query("DELETE FROM patient WHERE patientID={$patient_ID}") )    
      echo "user has been deleted successfully";
   else 
      echo "Error deleting";

  }

}

?>
```

now you'r good to go , after click delete button refresh your page and Boom! , the user will Disappears
and if you want a real time Action u can use (Ajax)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it still doesn't appear to work ... No errors are being thrown up, but it doesn't seem to delete anything in the table. I did however get it to work with this: if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
     $query = $conn->query("DELETE FROM `patient` WHERE PatientName = '$patientName' AND address = '$address'");
     echo "Record deleted!";
  }

Comment: However, for some reason it isn't deleting the record that's highlighted and rather just the first of the <select> options

Comment: @DeltaSierra ,thats why i said i prefer if u use `$Id` and record the "user id" in it, instead of "user name" (`$patientName'`).

Comment: @DeltaSierra , read my Comment again i update it here :  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42739325/7465452) ...........

Comment: I got it now. You're a lifesaver my friend. Apologies for my blinded approach to this.

Comment: Just did it. Again, thank you! Are there any websites you'd recommend me starting of learning PHP/MYSQL? There's thousands, but what have you used?

Comment: @DeltaSierra , np bro, in this website we have a session called : [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation) just go there and you'll find plenty programming languages, look in that list for `php` and `mysql` click and enter , you'll find a plenty topics and ofc start with ['Getting started with PHP' ] ,you'll find inside it plenty comments in each one there is a lesson or trick, so scrolldown the page and enjoy , after you finish get back to main Topic lists ( [php](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/topics) ) and chose the second leason ..... etc till you finish them all

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $patientName = $row['patientName'];
    $address = $row['address'];
    $patientID = $row['patientID'];  //get patient id
  echo "<option value=\"$patientID\">" .$patientName. ",  ".$address."</option>";  // change in option value
  }
```

Now on form submit, you will get patient id in     `$_POST['patient']` , can write your delete query.

Hope this will hope.

Comment: Hi, Bhaskar! Thanks for your response! I'm afraid that wasn't what I was asking for though. I wish to make a button that will delete the highlighted row from the <select> menu.

Comment: @DeltaSierra using jquery?

Comment: Only with PHP. Whenever the form is submitted, it would delete the entry. As in something like this: $conn->query("DELETE FROM `patient` WHERE patientName = ".$row['patientName']."")

Comment: Exactly what I have answered. select any patient from <select> dropdown and on form submit get patient id in $_POST['patient'], now you have to write your delete query. this will delete a record from database whose patient is selected.

Comment: @DeltaSierra Don't delete on `patientName`, what if you have two patients with the same name? Delete on `id`... also parameterize your query.

Comment: @chris85 I understand that principle, but as for this, it's only a school assignment that wants me to demonstrate the DELETE statement. I know what to delete.

Comment: @Bhaskar Apologies. I must've read your reply incorrectly or taken it out of context. I'll try your method and respond soon. Thanks!